# Threading not possible suggest any other way to do parallel processing

Tags: c#

My code in C# which i put in threading is not thread safe as it involves lots of database connections, stored procedure executions. but still i want to minimize the time required for the execution, can anyone suggest me something for parallel or asynchronous processing.. anything from database side or .net side...

I am stuck with threading.. not able to apply...

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to decrease execution time or improve GUI responsiveness during the call?  If the former, look to optimizing the number of database calls or benchmarking more generally to find your bottlenecks.  If looking to improve GUI responsiveness (because you're hanging your main thread), break the operation up into steps and perform each step one at a time for each main loop.

Comment: my code includes 1) execute stored procedure  2) use data from step 1 3)execute stored procedure 2 4) use data from step 3 5) and so on...please suggest to do something

Comment: Break each step and execute seperately . This will help you isolate the slowest of your calls and may give you a start point to optimize things . else your description is too vague that any thing specifically can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is not nearly enough information in your question to suggest an optimized solution.  However, if you must deal with resources that are not thread safe, one strategy is to spawn separate processes to handle sub-tasks.

Keep in mind, though, that separate processes still would have to handle portions of the overall solution that do not step on each other.

Comment: but every part of code produce some results which is used in other part of code... its a big code where only storedprocedures are executed .. i want to process a row from a table  .. and that processing involves number of stored procedure execution lots of....and i want to minimise time

Answer (score 0):

Well . There are couple of things that can be done . However I dont know how much it really fits you.

On database side you can do Query Optimizations , Indexing and other stuff that may help increase the query run time. Use profilers to analyse . See query plans to check if the indexes are properly used.

Use NOLOCKS but only where you see that you can USE NO LOCKS in your selects. (Not always a good practice but is used)

Implement proper Synchronized threading that can process multiple request. There is no other way from .Net Side. You have to review your design properly. However you can do code optimizations as well using profiler. You can use Task Library as well.

Other thing is There could be an issue with your server. Check CPU and Memory utilizations.
(This is my least of the concerns).

Comment: but every part of code produce some results which is used in other part of code... its a big code where only storedprocedures are executed .. i want to process a row from a table  .. and that processing involves number of stored procedure execution lots of....and i want to minimise time

Comment: Break your code that produces results into different part. Run them seperatly to see which part is slowing you down. This will help you to isolate the part causing the problem and they you can go from there. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should explain better what you are doing in your code...

If you do a lot of loops, you should try Parallel.For / Parallel.Foreach

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx

In Parallels you can also queue tasks for ordered computation or divide loops into blocks that could improve overall performance...

The best I can say, with so little information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but every part of code produce some results which is used in other part of code... its a big code where only storedprocedures are executed .. i want to process a row from a table  .. and that processing involves number of stored procedure execution lots of....and i want to minimise time

Comment: There are some parellels patterns that could help... Maybe this book can help you http://www.amazon.com/Parallel-Programming-Microsoft-NET-Decomposition/dp/0735651590/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1344284080&sr=8-6&keywords=parallels+library